# tkinter not responding when a text file is opened

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a tkinter program that has a button. The button's job is to open a text file on my desktop using notepad. Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os


def open_file():
    file = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/a.txt')
    os.system("notepad.exe " + file)


root = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(root, text='open', command=open_file)
button.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

The code runs and the program is working, but the problem is that when I click the button, the text file opens but tkinter window will be not responding until I close the text file. I am using Python 3 and Windows 10.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Use `os.system("start notepad.exe ...")` - the 'start' command returns once it's launched the indicated program.

Comment: Thanks. That worked!

Answer (score 1):

Just use: `os.system("start notepad.exe")`